# Firefox - built in search engine toolbar broken

Tags: firefox, toolbar, debug, search-engines

When I change the order of the search engines (Toolbar -> Manage Search Engines -> Move up / down -> Ok) it changes the order, until I close and reopen the browser.  I can't imagine that's the way it's supposed to work.  I want it to stay in the order I select.

I have no add-ons installed that have anything to do with search engines, nor that add any toolbars.

I am not using a customized theme.

Apparently this problem is rare, as Googling [ "manage search engine list" ("order reverts" OR "order changes") ] return 0 results.

Firefox 3.6.12; Windows XP Pro SP3.

Comment: Anyone have an idea???

Comment: You might want to try and run Firefox in Safe mode and see if is saves the order then. If it doesn't, reinstall Firefox and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you forget about this problem and install web search pro, features:

- You can change the order of your engines =).
- There are more engines to add to the list than firefox has.
- You can drag and drop to engines with a special feature called zones(temporarly divives firefox into a grid of search engines).
- Perfect integration with firefox.
- No ads of any kind.
- Compatibility with all the firefox versions.
- You have a lot of options to control the behavior of the searching.

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/web-search-pro/

Comment: I have added a couple search engines to that list by simply dropping the shortcut to them in there - so there's no limit to the number that can be added.  I add extensions to add functionality.  I don't want to add an extension to fix broken functionality.  This problem may indicate something else is also wrong.

Comment: -1 for not posting a language-neutral URL

Comment: Thanks.  Now my question doesn't show up in the "not answered" list on the main page.  I asked how to fix a bug, not what add-ons are available.  I realize you meant well...

Comment: -Thanks a lot.  The non-answer removed my post from the non-answered list.  I flagged it as a non-answer, but the moderators have not removed it.

Comment: -1 not an answer to the question

Comment: Though folks might not find this useful, why do people flag this as spam or offensive? **That might seriously impact the user's reputation here!** And as for the non-language-neutral URL, @Hello71: you do have editing rights, why didn't you fix that URL, rather than spending time to comment...? And @Victor, do you expect us to fix bugs here? Then this is not the place to be.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove them all, restart, then re-add them in your preferred order?

Or, in Firefox 3.6, your search engine settings are stored in `search.sqlite` in your profile folder.  On Windows XP it's something like

`C:\Documents and Settings\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\randomstuff\search.sqlite`

You could download [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3070400.zip), extract the file into somewhere (e.g. c:\sqlite), close Firefox completely, then open a Command Prompt and do something like this:

```
c:\> set PATH=%PATH%;c:\sqlite
c:\> cd %APPDATA%
c:\> cd Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
c:\> cd <TAB>
c:\> sqlite3 search.sqlite
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE engine_data (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, engineid STRING, name STRING,
value STRING);
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info('engine_data');
0|id|INTEGER|0||1
1|engineid|STRING|0||0
2|name|STRING|0||0
3|value|STRING|0||0
sqlite> select * from engine_data;
2|[app]/google.xml|order|1
3|[app]/yahoo.xml|order|2
4|[app]/wikipedia.xml|order|3
5|[app]/amazondotcom.xml|order|4
6|[app]/answers.xml|order|5
7|[app]/creativecommons.xml|order|6
8|[app]/eBay.xml|order|7
9|[app]/google.xml|used|1
sqlite> update engine_data set value=2 where name='order' and engineid like '%wikipedia%;
sqlite> update engine_data set value=3 where name='order' and engineid like '%yahoo%;
sqlite> update engine_data set value=4 where name='order' and engineid like '%ebay%;
sqlite> .quit
```

Where you change the number after `value=` to whatever number you want and the bit between the `%` to one of the options printed by `select * from engine_data;`.